# Syntastic checking for embedded handlebars code?

Tags: gvim, plugin-syntastic

I'm editing some HTML, which has embedded [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templates. For example:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<tr>
    <td>{{ id }}</td>
    <td>{{ address }}</td>
    <td>{{ num_connections }}</td>
</tr>
</script>
```

Syntastic doesn't like it, and complains about `'<' + '/' + letter not allowed here`.

Can I get Syntastic to do something more intelligent with embedded templates?

Comment: Check it as `handlebars`, rather than `html`.  The manual is your friend.

Comment: Which manual? Does this apply to the whole file? If not, how do I apply it to just the embedded bit?

Comment: Which version of syntastic? `:h syntastic`, `:h syntastic-handlebars-handlebars`; whole file.

Comment: You could write actual HTML, for example. Or actual handlebars.

Comment: @romainl, what I'm doing is **right there on the handlebars getting started page**: http://handlebarsjs.com/#getting-started, so I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @lcd047 no idea, `:h syntastic` reports "Sorry, no help for syntastic". It's commit 5c6e78a, installed using pathogen.

Comment: Upgrade syntastic to the latest master HEAD, then run `:Helptags` (`pathogen` command to index the help).

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, there's no such thing as `text/x-handlebars-template` so HTML linters may not like that hack. Linting that document as "handlebars" would almost certainly work.